# Creating a class to represent a playing card

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Card class to represent playing cards. The code on the bottom runs the code on the top. I just need help getting started. I'm not exactly sure how to though. How would I create the constructor for this class also?

```
public class Card
{
  public static final String FACES[] = {"ZERO","ACE","TWO","THREE","FOUR",
  "FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","JACK","QUEEN","KING"};

//instance variables
    //String suit
    //int face

//constructors


// modifiers
    //set methods


//accessors
    //get methods


//toString

 }
```

---

```
public class CardRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
    Card one = new Card("SPADES", 9);
    out.println(one.getSuit());
    out.println(one.getFace());

    Card two = new Card("DIAMONDS", 1);
    out.println(two);
    two.setFace(3);
    out.println(two);

    Card three = new Card("CLUBS", 4);
    out.println(three);

    Card four = new Card("SPADES", 12);
    out.println(four);

    Card five = new Card("HEARTS", 12);
    out.println(five);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use an `enum` here for `PlayingCard` because all are constants and you can override `toString` to give meaningful representation.

If you create enum, you do not have to create objects explicitly and can use enum constants whenever you want to use. You can read a nice tutorial on [why to use enumerations in java](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/01/why-use-enumerations-in-java/)

Comment: The suit and face properties could also be made enums.